# is there any way to invoke UPI app on device

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, upi, flutter-razorpay

I have integrated razorpay with flutter and everything is working .But it is not invoking the upi app present in device.how to do that?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/upi_pay
https://pub.dev/packages/upi_india

Answer (score 5):

```
void _launchURL() async {
    String _url='upi://pay?pa=dinesh@dlanzer&pn=Dinesh&am=1&tn=Test Payment&cu=INR';
    var result = await launch(_url);
     debugPrint(result.toString());
     if (result ==true) {
       print("Done");
     } else if (result ==false){
       print("Fail");
     }
  }
```

Try this code

I use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) plugin for open UPI apps.

Deeplink url `'upi://pay?pa=dinesh@dlanzer&pn=Dinesh&am=1&tn=Test Payment&cu=INR'`,

`upi` show list of UPI apps you have in your mobile.

`pay` is redirect to payment page.

`pa` you mention upi address here (please make business upi account and mention here).

`am` amount enter here.

`tn` just pass massage.

`cu` mention which currency you want to make payment

Comment: FYI, this url works for android only, for IOS you need to specify the url for the app you want to call. example `phonepe://upi/pay?..........` if you want to open phonepe

Comment: It's universal standard deeplink url. You also use this same url to anywhere for IOS, android & web also. But web you need some customization

Comment: how to know if the payment was successful or not?

Comment: @Jagadish I think it is not possible to check if the payment was successful or not. If you want that kind of functionality then you will have to integrate payment gateways.

Comment: I tried using this in Flutter web. It invokes the GPay app alright but gives an error that says 'Invalid QR code. Oops something went wrong!' Any idea what needs to be done

Comment: `pn` means name ?

Comment: Yes, pn is name